# Eclipse Wizard plugin executes code for all pages at once

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an Eclipse plugin which utilizes `Wizard` and `WizardPage` classes.

At the moment, whenever I add a page, the code related to this page is executed. This is not what I need, since some pages rely on input provided on previous pages.

How can I add this dependency between pages?

Here is example:

The first page has buttons for probing the device. When the device is available, I can go to the next page and see some features this device provides. When I open the wizard without a connected device, the Wizard executes code from second page, which isn't intended to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the wizard page `setVisible` method and add the code which depends on previous pages there

```java
@Override
public void setVisible(final boolean visible)
{
  super.setVisible(visible);

  if (visible)
   {
      ... code to run when page becomes visible
   }
}
```